# Mypy complains about __setitem__ signature

Tags: python, mypy

I have a subclass of `list` that adds some administrative stuff on the components of the list. Everything works OK, but `mypy` complains about signature of the `super` call to `__setitem__`.
Here is the problem reduced to its bare minimum:

```
from typing import List, Iterable, Union, overload
from typing_extensions import SupportsIndex


class MyData:
    pass


class MyDataSeq(List[MyData]):
    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, index: SupportsIndex, value: MyData) -> None: ...

    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, index: slice, value: Iterable[MyData]) -> None: ...

    def __setitem__(self, index: Union[SupportsIndex, slice], value: Union[MyData, Iterable[MyData]]) -> None:
        # Administrative stuff deleted
        super().__setitem__(index, value)

    def __delitem__(self, index: Union[SupportsIndex, slice]) -> None:
        # Administrative stuff deleted
        super().__delitem__(index)
```

When I run `mypy` on this, I get:

```
src\seq.py:18: error: Invalid index type "Union[SupportsIndex, slice]" for "MyDataSeq"; expected type "SupportsIndex"
src\seq.py:18: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[MyData, Iterable[MyData]]", target has type "MyData")
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I'm at a loss here, because obviously `__setitem__`, just like `__delitem__`, accepts both an `int`-like (`SupportsIndex`) and a `slice` object as its first argument. It is almost as if `mypy` somehow reaches the conclusion that only `int`-like objects are supported -- that matches with the second error that it expects only a `MyData` as second argument, not `Iterable[MyData]`.

I have tried this on both Python 3.7 and 3.9, the errors are the same.
I can of course tell `mypy` to ignore these errors, but I really would like to know what causes this, and how to solve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As for [this](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7858) similar issue, Mypy doesn't use overload information to type-check the function body.

To solve your problem, you could [give a hint](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#complex-type-tests) to Mypy what types you are passing to it by means of `isinstance`. Like so:

```py
from typing import List, Iterable, Union, overload
from typing_extensions import SupportsIndex


class MyData:
    pass


class MyDataSeq(List[MyData]):
    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, index: SupportsIndex, value: MyData) -> None: ...

    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, index: slice, value: Iterable[MyData]) -> None: ...

    def __setitem__(self, index: Union[SupportsIndex, slice], value: Union[MyData, Iterable[MyData]]) -> None:
        # Administrative stuff deleted
        if isinstance(index, slice) and isinstance(value, Iterable):
            super().__setitem__(index, value)
        elif isinstance(index, int) and isinstance(value, MyData):
            super().__setitem__(index, value)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"{index}/{value} Invalid index/value type.")

    def __delitem__(self, index: Union[SupportsIndex, slice]) -> None:
        # Administrative stuff deleted
        super().__delitem__(index)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to annotate the implementation, only the decorated definitions.

```
class MyDataSeq(List[MyData]):
    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, index: SupportsIndex, value: MyData) -> None:
        ...

    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, index: slice, value: Iterable[MyData]) -> None:
       ...

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        # Administrative stuff deleted
        super().__setitem__(index, value)

    def __delitem__(self, index: Union[SupportsIndex, slice]) -> None:
        # Administrative stuff deleted
        super().__delitem__(index)
```

(This will leave a similar problem for `__delitem__` to be resolved, but I think that's a matter for a separate question.)

Comment: It is not an actual solution. Annotating implementation is a way to go, because otherwise implementation is not checked (without flag `--check-untyped-defs`), so you don't get all type checking benefits. `mypy` team recommends annotating implementation with `Union`s of overloads types. And it doesn't actually answer the question, because your answer just suggests something similar to `# type: ignore` (and even worse, because type checking is completely silenced without explicit marker), and does not explain *why* this happens. (downvote mine)